# Is there a way to use @PreAuthorize in Getters? (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to use different objects for different user roles.

```
@Component    
public class TestObject {
        private String name;
        private String secret;

        @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        public String getSecret() {
            return secret;
        }
        public void setSecret(String secret) {
            this.secret = secret;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to use @PreAuthorize like this?

Comment: `@PreAuthorize` will only work in spring managed beans. So yes it will work, but only if `TestObject` is managed by Spring, which I doubt it is (you probably want to annotate entities or the likes).

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried to use @ Component, but it doesn't work too

Comment: Just adding `@Component` doesn't make it spring managed. Might be that there is one created by Spring but that probably isn't the one you are going to use.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried it too with a method on a service, with the @ service annotation. This should be a managed bean by spring, so it's strange

Comment: You also need `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` else the `@PreAuthorize` won't do anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum I can use the @ PreAuthoriz on Controller level, so this is activated

Comment: If you are creating instances of that service or whatever class yourself it isn't spring managed. So make sure you are injecting the instance you need instead of creating it yourself. Also make sure that you aren't using different contexts (child/parent) as that would also require additional activation of method security (AOP is only applied in the application context it is defined in, not in parents and childs of that context!).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PreAuthorize` only in a Spring Managed Bean.

If you have to create multiple instances of an object, these instances are not managed by the application context.

If you mark a class with `@Component`, this becomes a Spring bean and can be injected and managed by the application context. Now, if **you** (not Spring) create a instance of this class, then this specific instance isn't a managed by Spring.

This means, that `@PreAuthorize` will not work in this instance.

One workaround is to use the `SecurityContextHolder`.

Something like this:

**Utils.java**

```
public class Utils {

    public static boolean isAdmin() {
        Collection<?extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority: authorities) {
            if (authority.getAuthority().equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

**TestObject.java**

```
public class TestObject {

    private String name;
    private String secret;

    public String getSecret() {
        if(Utils.isAdmin())
            return secret;

        return null;
    }
    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```